# I have some troubles in making slide menu bar with sass

Tags: html, css, sass, menubar

Hi  I'm learning html and css by Youtube tutorial, how to slide out navigation with css/html, but I've stucked with some codes.
Everything is working fine except

```
#sidebartoggler
display: none

&:checked + .page-wrap
 .sidebar
    left:0px
```

this one. When I click this, the sidebar should come out but it isn't.

I tried to fix the problem, trying to find anything wrong on my code for two days, but I couldn't and exhausted.

It would be a great help for me to figure what is wrong.
Please help me

ps. youtube link is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d4P8s-mkMvs

```css
@import 'bourbon'

.page-content
 position: relative
 z-index:0

.toggle
 text-decoration: none
 font-size:30px
 color: black
 +position(fixed, 20px 0 0 200px)
 z-index:1
 
.sidebar
 +position(fixed, 0px 0 0px 0px)
 width: 120px
 padding: 30px
 background: #333
 z-index:0
 
 
 
 li
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8)
  font-family: "Ubuntu",sans-serif
  font-size: 16px
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased
  margin-bottom: 16px
  cursor:pointer
  
  &:hover
   color: rgba(255,255,255,1)

#sidebartoggler
 display: none
 
 &:checked + .page-wrap
  .sidebar
  left:0px
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
 <head>
   <title>GagaPro</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slidebar.css">
 </head>
 
 <body>
 
  <input type="checkbox" id="sidebartoggler" name="" value="">
  
  <div class="page-wrap">
   <label for="sidebartoggler" class="toggle">☰</label>
  
  </div>
 
  <div class="page-content">
   <div class="wrapper">
   
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="sidebar">
   <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Project</li>
    <li>Client</li>
    <li>Blog</li>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Home</li>
   
   </ul>
  
  </div>
   
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code using normal css and i found some thing cool.

No need to change any thing in HTML, only css will change little bit

CSS :

```
 .page-content{
        position: relative;
        z-index:0;
    }
    .toggle{
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size:30px;
        color: black;
        +position(fixed, 20px 0 0 200px);
        z-index:1;
        }
    .sidebar{
        +position(fixed, 0px 0 0px 0px);
        width: 120px;
        padding: 30px;
        background: #333;
        z-index:0;
        display:none;
        }

        li{
            color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
            font-family: "Ubuntu",sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            margin-bottom: 16px;
            cursor:pointer;
            }
            li:hover{
                color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
          }
    #sidebartoggler{
        display:none;
     }

    #sidebartoggler:checked ~ .sidebar{
         display:block;
    }
```